# Returning data from Executor service

Tags: android, executorservice, android-room, android-livedata, android-jetpack

This is my first time working with executor services. I am trying to return data from an ExecutorService, while having trouble with the return type. Currently I am getting data from my database, this is called by my repository and returned. I am trying to use an ExecutorService to do this. Here is my code

```
public LiveData<List<User>> getUsers(int limit) {
    try{
        return mIoExecutor.submit(mDao.getUsers(limit), LiveData<List<User>>)
    }catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}
```

and my database

```
 @Query("select * from smiley ORDER BY name, RANDOM() LIMIT :limit")
LiveData<List<User>> getUsers(int limit);
```

The issue is, that ExecutorService is asking for an expression instead of LiveData>.

Comment: I believe you have a syntax error - unclosed chevron bracket `LiveData<List<User>`.

Answer (score 3):

One has to pass `Runnable` there and I've added a seconds parameter `start`, because `limit` is useless, unless knowing where to start loading from, as it is common for pagination or a pager.

```
private MutableLiveData<List<User>> users;

public void getUsers(final int start, final int limit) {
    try {
        this.mIoExecutor.submit((Runnable) () -> {
            List<User> data = mDao.getUsers(start, limit);
            users.postValue(data);
        });
    } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple methods one can use for submitting the task. The two basic ones being **`execute()`** and **`submit()`**.

Here are the key differences:

- **`void execute(Runnable command)`** - executes a `Runnable` task
- **`Future<?> submit(Runnable task)`** - executes a `Runnable` task, returns a Future representing the task
- **`<T> Future<T> submit(Callable<T> task)`** - executes a `Callable` task, returns a `Future` representing the pending results of the task

You are correctly using a **`submit()`** method, which is returning information about the executed task.

When retrieving the information returned by the `submit()` method, note the following:

1. Method **`submit()` returns `Future` object**. In order to retrieve the information about the task, **we need to retrieve the information from the `Future` object**, using `get()` method. Two are available:

   - `V get()`
   - `V get(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)`
2. **The task might not yet be done by the time of information request**. We can use `Future.isDone()` method to make sure the task completed (note that this method returns true also, if the task threw an exception or was cancelled).
3. **We need to submit a `Callable` object**. As mentioned above, there are two `submit()` methods, one accepting a **`Runnable`** and one a **`Callable`**. Both are functional interfaces, with the key difference:

   - `Runnable` - it's `run()` method, accepts no value and returns on value, it cannot throw an exception
   - `Callable` - it's `call()` method returns a value and can throw an exception

Calling `get()` on a `Future` object, will return the same return type as defined by a `call()` method, or `null` if `Runnable` object was submitted (method `run()` returns no value).